# How to configure master-slave with 2 nodes using redis-cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

How to configure master-slave with 2 nodes using redis-cluster

I previously used redis-sentinel
I created a master-salve with 2 nodes.
I am asked to change from redis-sentinel to redis-cluster.

I want to use redis-cluster with the following requirements

- 2 node HA (1 master node, 1 slave node)
- Do not use sharding, use only replication settings

I think redis-cluster cannot fail over automatically if there are at least 3 master nodes.
[Redis cluster failover: slave won't become master](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444797/redis-cluster-failover-slave-wont-become-master)

How can I use redis-cluster for automatic failover on two nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis Cluster minimum specification is 6 instances and sharding is not something you can just turn off.
You theoretically run 3 instances on each node but it will not give you highly available cluster.

Comment: Hi Elad, is it possible to have 3 masters and only 2 slaves within Redis Cluster?? My question is asking if we can have fewer slaves than the masters?

Comment: Each slave replicate exactly one master. As a result, having fewer slaves than masters means you have at least one master that is not replicated by a slave. This means that portion of the data is not replicated.

Comment: So how about if my cluster has 4 masters and 3 replicate? So there's gonna be 1 master without a slave, right? So can the cluster be up and running or it's just can't? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cluster can run with 4 masters and 3 slaves but it is considered unhealthy state since some of the data is persisted only in one place

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. Thanks for your clear clarification.